# Remove Special Character From String

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nscharacterset

I have a String W

```
        NSString * stringTitle  = link.title;
```

where i am getting **link.title as @"I_AM_GOOD"**;

I need to remove the special characters "_" and make is as "I am Good".How to do that?

Comment: do u need to replace the "_" replaced by space or remove special character

Comment: replace "_" by space and remove other special characters if it comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined what you mean by a special character, and you seem to want to replace it with a space, not remove it.

```
NSArray * comps = [stringTitle componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"]

NSString * result = nil;
for(NSString *s in comps)
{
   if(result)
   {
      result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",[s capitalizedString];
   }
   else
   {
       result = [s capitalizedString];
   }
}
```

If you have other special characters that you want to replace, then use

```
-componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
```

Comment: Thanks man that works. How to use the character in set, if i need to replace others too?

Comment: You need to post a specific question (preferably with some code that isn't doing what you want, rather than just "how can I do this"). Adjusting the question in a comment thread is not helpful to anyone searching later on.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to replace any characeter from a string is as below. Make sure that you use a `NSMutableString`.

```
[stringTitle replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,[stringTitle length])];
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way to do it

```
strTest = [strTest stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];
```